# Laravel 5.4 Storage::delete() not working (method delete not found)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having an issue getting `Storage::delete($filepath);` to work in Laravel 5.4.

I have searched for other people with this issue, but the error most others seem to have is providing the file path without the preceding `/`, however this is not my issue.

I am using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` (as per the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#deleting-files)) and I have noticed I am getting an error in PHPStorm saying `Method delete not found in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage`.

My code looks like;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
// also tried use Storage;
...

public function deleteFile($id)
{
    try {
        $image = Files::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
        Storage::delete($image->filepath);
        return Files::destroy($id);

    } catch ( \Exception $e) {
        return back()->with('alert-warning', 'Something went wrong: ' . $e);
    }
}
```

My $image->filepath looks like `/Users/usrname/sites/sitename/storage/app/images/34/o8Aq1T3Hi67sOtuTgBh9P7QWA1Ahj4KH2QBR77n0.png`

Anyone able to help?

Comment: It is not supposed to be in the facade. Have a look at how facades work exactly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#how-facades-work Also, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper is a great dev tool that helps prevent these IDE issues and gives much better code completion

Comment: @Pevara thanks for that, I will check it out. Do you have any ideas why this is not working though? Unfortunately no error message that I can see..?

Comment: that should be `use Storage`, not `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage`

Comment: (also `Files::findOrFail($id)` would probably be cleaner, but that has nothing to do with your issue)

Comment: I tried use Storage, that does not fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK so it turns out that the $filepath needs to be relative to the storage root of the app, not the full file path to the file!

I used a function to update my file path to;

`images/34/o8Aq1T3Hi67sOtuTgBh9P7QWA1Ahj4KH2QBR77n0.png` and it works a charm.

Comment: Also mention that if www-data doesn't have permissions to delete that file, it won't delete it and you won't get any error neither. So make sure that www-data has the rights to delete files in the storage folder. PHP `unlink` will throw errors that Laravel Storage wont, so you can use that functions instead for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 15):

I had another problem, I was calling

```
Storage::delete($path);
```

without a disk, so I put this, and it work.

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete($path);
```

Answer (score 4):

in : config/filesystems.php by default :

```
'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

so if your image is in storage/app/public/ folder, your storage image path should be:

'public/image.jpg'

To delete this image from storage you should write :

```
Storage::delete('public/image.jpg)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error, tried File::delete() then it worked.

Comment: This was the most reliable method for me as well